# Using Sinatra and DataMapper, are classes one and the same?

Tags: ruby, class, sinatra, datamapper

When declaring classes in a sinatra app for data mapper, I understand it would look something like this:

```
class Thing
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,     Serial
  property :name,   String
  property :num,    Integer
end
```

And if this wasn't a web app, but just desktop ruby program, you might do something like this:

```
class Thing
  def initialize(name, num)
    @name = name
    @num = num
  end
  def doTheThing(num)
    num * 2
  end
end
```

So would it make sense to do...

```
class Thing
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,     Serial
  property :name,   String
  property :num,    Integer

  def initialize(name, num)
    @name = name
    @num = num
  end
  def doTheThing(num)
    num * 2
  end
end
```

(edit) Forgot my question: Is this valid? Any opinions or things I've missed here? Thanks!

I'm currently working on my first semi-large sinatra project, and would appreciate the help.

On a related note, any suggestions for good examples of code to study (sinatra/ruby web apps and such) would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You question is a bit fuzzy. Prefer to ask fairly specific questions. Asking for general tips or examples is generally frowned upon. Try to explain what you want to do, what you've tried and how that attempt didn't fullfil your expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different implementations you provided don't have anything inherently to do with Sinatra or the web or desktop applications. A desktop app can use Datamapper to persist objects, and a Sinatra app may use any kind of Plain Old Ruby Objects.

That said, the third implementation will probably cause problems. The reason is that `DataMapper::Resource` [defines a method called `initialize`](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core/blob/master/lib/dm-core/resource.rb#L733) which you then overwrite with your own version.

It is not uncommon for model classes to contain additional methods that you've written yourself. These can, for example, encapsulate some kind of business logic that is based upon the persisted attributes.

So to try to answer you question: all of your classes are valid but the last one is probably not very wise.

Comment: Thanks for answering - it was pretty vague. So you're saying that besides `initialize`, the class will act like a regular ruby class?

Comment: The class *is* a regular ruby class. *All* your classes are regular ruby classes. Mixing in a module doesn't make your class something else than a regular ruby class. Overriding `initialize` doesn't make your class less "regular", but since the included module also defines `initialize`, you may run into unexpected behavior by overriding it. For example, other pieces of code in the module may depend on that particular implementation of `initialize`, but I'm not sure.